# What's the difference returning & and not?

Tags: c++

I still haven't figured out how the `&` works in the compiler.

To figure it out, I tried disassembling the code below:

```cpp
private:
        int data;
public:
int& at()
{
    return data;
}
int at()
{
    return data;
}

const int& result = mymay.at(); //call the two functions
```

I find that `int& at()` returns an address, and `int at()` returns a value; the compiler first writes the value to a memory, then "result"'s address was set to it.
So I understand that `int at()` will return a copied one.
I also understand that it's best practice to write `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os , const A &obj)`

But I wonder if it's correct: in the below code, `A &get1()` returns an `l-value`, and `A get2()` returns an `r-value`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    A &get1(){
        return *this;
    }
    A get2(){
        return *this;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os , A &obj){
        cout<<"An l-value function called."<<endl;
        return os;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os , A &&obj){
        cout<<"An r-value function called."<<endl;
        return os;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A tmp;
    cout<<"get1: "<<tmp.get1()<<"get2: "<<tmp.get2()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Actual results:

```
An l-value function called.
An r-value function called.
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: I only wonder if it's correct:in the code bihind,A &get1() returns an l-value,A get2() return an r-value.

Comment: That depends what you want to do with the result.

Comment: @user7476499 That is right. `int & f()` returns a reference and `int f()` returns a copy.

Comment: @user7476499: "*I still don't figure out how the & work in the compiler.*" You shouldn't. You should focus on what the language says about the code, what the code means. Trying to retroactively understand C++ by looking at the assembly output is not going to work well. The compiler has way too much freedom to make optimizations, alterations, reordering, and even out-right omissions, so long as the program's behavior doesn't change from what the standard says.

Comment: @user7476499 *How* references work is up to the implementation of the language you are using. Trying to understand how it works under the hood may be interesting but it's not relevant to c++ in a general sense. It may very well not be true in other versions of your compiler or other compilers. But most importantly it may lead you to believe things about the language that it does not guarantee. It's not because your implementation does something with references that it's safe to assume every other implementation will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version of `at` that returns a reference allows you to modify the member datum `data` via that reference:

```
mymay.at() = 1;
```

will set `data` in the instance of `mymay` to 1. So `mymay.at()` is an *l-value*: i.e. it can be placed on the left hand side of an assignment.

The version of `at` that returns a value will not allow you to do that. It's not an *l-value*.

---

Your second point, an *l-value* cannot bind to an *rvalue reference* `&&` wheres an *anonymous temporary* can. Overload resolution for your `cout` is unambiguous which accounts for the output of your program.